# continuing the execution of the code when false

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, for-loop

Can you please help me with this. I have this code:

```
foreach ($mat_desc as $mat_key => $materials) {
    $mat = explode(' | ', $materials);
    $mat_d = $mat[0];
    $mat_u = $mat[1];
    $m = mat_id_from_mat_desc($mat_d, $mat_u);

    $cur = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT `req_id` FROM `requestdetails` JOIN `request` USING(`req_id`) WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.$m.'" AND `req_qty` <> `current_rec_qty` ORDER BY `req_id` DESC'), 0);
    echo $cur;
    if(mysql_num_rows($cur) == 0){
        exit;
    }

    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `receive` (`proj_id`,`rec_code`) VALUES ('$proj_id','$rec_code')");       

    $rec_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

What I want to achieve is that, when `$cur` doesn't have any rows it will exit the loop and not continue to the rest of the code. But if it does have any rows, it will continue and execute the insert query. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$cur = mysql_query('SELECT `req_id` FROM `requestdetails` JOIN `request` USING(`req_id`) WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.$m.'" AND `req_qty` <> `current_rec_qty` ORDER BY `req_id` DESC');

echo $cur;
if(mysql_num_rows($cur) == 0){
   exit;
}
```

Also, you should not be using the `mysql_` extensions. Try using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you mean is that you want to not execute the `INSERT` *for that item* in the `foreach` statement. If that's the case, change `exit;` to `continue;` which will instruct PHP to stop executing the code for the current item in the loop, advance one element in the loop and start from the top again.

You should also change:

```
$cur = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT `req_id` FROM `requestdetails` JOIN `request` USING(`req_id`) WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.$m.'" AND `req_qty` <> `current_rec_qty` ORDER BY `req_id` DESC'), 0);
```

to:

```
 $cur = mysql_query('SELECT `req_id` FROM `requestdetails` JOIN `request` USING(`req_id`) WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.$m.'" AND `req_qty` <> `current_rec_qty` ORDER BY `req_id` DESC');
```

Comment: No sir. The insert query is for the whole loop. If one item satisfies the condition in my if statement, it will not continue to the rest of the code.

Comment: @chris Do you just want to exit? Or do you want to `break;` instead which will stop further iterations of the loop, but allow you to do something outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `continue;` in place of `exit;` it will skip to the next item in the loop. If you want to end the loop once and for all you would use `break;` in place of `exit;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to abort the `foreach` loop completely use `break`:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($cur) == 0){
    break;
}
```

If you want to advance to the next iteration of the `foreach` loop, discarding the rest of the current `foreach` iteration code, use `continue`:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($cur) == 0){
    continue;
}
```

`exit` is used to end the complete php script, and is synonym to `die`.